# Passing a generic struct as a parameter in an interface

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, struct

In C++, suppose I have a messaging system that wraps messages in a generic struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Message
{
  std::string Name;
  T Data;
};
```

I also have an interface that includes functions that need to use the purely generic version of this struct:

```
class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() { }
    virtual void Receive(Message& message) = 0;
    virtual Message Send() = 0;
};
```

However, `Message` no longer names a type; things like `Message<float>` and `Message<std::string>` name types. Since the classes that will be implementing `Interface` will want to catch different `Message`, I can't just define a specific type.

The only way I can think to fix this is to rip out the template and using inheritance, but then I'd have littered throughout my code things like `IntMessage` and `BoolMessage`, which looks extraordinarily ugly. Any thoughts on how I can do this the way I want?

Comment: What attribute(s)/method(s) does the "purely generic version" of the `Message` have? Just the `Name`?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>A simple approach is to split the `Message` type into a hierarchy:</strike>

```
struct MessageBase {
  std::string Name;
};
template<typename T>
struct Message : MessageBase
{
  T Data;
};
```

Then you can just pass `MessageBase&` through interfaces.

[The previous won't work. The function will be able to accept any `MessageBase&` object, but `Receive` seems to be about storing in the argument a message for which the type is unknown a compile time. Although if you don't mind dynamic allocations you could have a `Message` that holds the name and a pointer to a `MessageBase` and then different implementations of `MessageImpl` (the template above)]

Another common approach is to add all possible messages to an union and pass the union around.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define your interface as a template?

```
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() { }
    virtual void Receive(Message<T>& message) = 0;
    virtual Message<T> Send() = 0;
};
```

Comment: @twalberg it isn't clear how the template messages could really be virtual.

Comment: @twalberg You can't have template virtual methods can you?